# Can I return pointer to VLA?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer, c11

Is such function prototype valid in C?

```
int (*func())[*];
```

And if it is, how can I define such functions?

Comment: Most of the time, if you think you want to return a pointer to an array, what you really want to do is return a pointer to the array's first element. With a pointer to the first element, you can do `p[5]` to get the 5th element; with a pointer to the whole array, you would need to do `p[0][5]` or `(*p)[5]`.

Comment: it should be enough to replace `[*]` by `[]`

Comment: How is the prototype related to the question? Looks like you're trying to declare an array of function pointers, but that's not the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @harald: It's an attempt to declare a function returning a pointer to a variable-length array of ints. Similar syntax (`int (*func())[5]`) works for declaring a function that returns a pointer to a fixed-size array.

Comment: the section that forbids pointer-to-VLAs is possibly 6.7.6.2 §2: *If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it shall [...] have either block scope or function prototype scope.*; not sure if there's something more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 2. ...(A function prototype is a declaration of a function that **declares the types of its parameters**.)

and (6.7.6.2 Array declarators)

> 4. ...If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, **which can only
>      be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope**;

So you may not specify return type of the function such a way as you showed.

Take into account that 1) functions may not have return types of arrays and 2) variable length arrays have automatic storage duration. Thus if such an array could be returned the function had undefined behaviour. See 6.7.6.2 Array declarators:

> 2 If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it
>   shall be an ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no
>   linkage, and have either block scope or function prototype scope. **If
>   an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread
>   storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.**

I know two approaches to your problem. Either allocate an array dynamically and return a poinetr to its first element. Or pack an array in a structure. In this case you can return the whole structure from a function as an rvalue.

Comment: 1) doesn't apply as he wants to return a pointer, 2) does not necessarily apply if the array that gets returned was passed in as an argument

Comment: @Christoph  Why do you have decided that he  wants to return a pointer when he wrote explicitly a variable length array as the return type? So it is your comment that has nothing common with the question.

Comment: because the title of the question is *Can I return **pointer** to VLA?* (which is also what his declaration does)

Comment: @Christoph  First of all the function does not have a parameter, So you referencing to parameters as arrays are irrelative to the question. And secondly as I have written in my post VLA(s) have atomatic storage duration. Thus returning a pointer to such an array has undefined behaviour.

Comment: actually, the prototype comes with an empty argument list, which means it takes an unspecified number of arguments adjusted according to the rules of default argument promotion; but I do see your point, assuming the OP wants to allocate a VLA within a function

Comment: I've never mentioned such a thing. I was just curios about the syntax and whatever usage can it have.

Comment: @FISOCPP The only usage I envision such a function might have has to do with allocating an array of such a type or reallocating such an array, similar to `malloc` and `realloc`. You'd require two size parameters and, in the case of reallocation, a pointer to a 1-D array. In other words, you already declared `int (*array_2D)[X];` in your caller, and you're assigning to it the result of `int (*foo_alloc(size_t m, size_t n))[];` to allocate a 2-D array of size `m * n`, where `X` would be passed in place of `n`. A function pointer to such a function would be `int (*(*allocfn)(size_t, size_t))[];`

Comment: To make it easier to understand, you'd probably use a `typedef`: `typedef int (*ArrayPtr)[]; ArrayPtr foo_alloc(size_t, size_t); ArrayPtr (*allocfn)(size_t, size_t);`

Answer (score 5):

You should return a pointer to an incomplete array type instead as `*` notation for variable-length arrays is only valid in parameter lists.

Example prototype and function definition:

```
extern float (*first_row(unsigned, unsigned, float (*)[*][*]))[];

float (*first_row(unsigned n, unsigned m, float (*matrix)[n][m]))[]
{
    return *matrix;
}
```

You'd invoke it like this:

```
unsigned n = 3, m = 4;
float matrix[n][m];
float (*row)[m] = first_row(n, m, &matrix);
```

Note that it is undefined behaviour to return a pointer to an array (variable-length or otherwise) that has been declared *within* the function  if it has automatic storage duration. This implies that you can only return a pointer to a variable-length array that you passed in as an argument or allocated dynamically.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, a function `f` could also return a pointer to a VLA allocated with malloc, with something like `int (*p)[m] = malloc(…);`, after which it could usefully return `p` and it would be nice if the C type system allowed the `m` to be transferred more automatically from the type of `p` to the lvalue that receives the result of `f()`. But apparently this is not possible : the `m` has to be repeated with all the risk of error that this implies in `float (*recipient)[m] = f();`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: also note that you could in principle avoid repeating yourself by using a `typedef`

Comment: I do not see how for the case I have in mind (expressing that `f(size_t m)` creates and initializes an array of size `m` and returns a pointer to this array, that should be placed into a variable of type “pointer to array of size `m`”).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I was thinking of my example, where I could have introduced a `typedef float row_of_m[m]` and declared both `matrix` and `row` that way (and possibly even added another prototype of `first_row` using that type?); you're right that this does not help with the use-case you had in mind; I'd advocate against introducing such a typedef anyway due to its negative impact on readability

Answer (score -1):

Tecnically you can, but it's not a good idea.

```
int * func(size_t s)
{
    int array[s];
    return array;
}
```

After being defined a variable length array is no different than a regular array, so it decays to a pointer when you try to return it. Returning a pointer to a local variable results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is not a function returning pointer to VLA. It's one returning just a pointer to integer. It doesn't help me.

Comment: The question does not say that the VLA being pointed to has to go out of scope as the function returns.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, true, but unless you want to pass the array in and return a pointer to the same array, I don't really see any other way. VLAs are not allowed in static scope.

Comment: @harald See my comment on Christoph's answer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, dynamic allocation is of course an entirely different beast and lifts most restrictions.